# Write array elements on new line in text file

Tags: php, arrays, file

I am trying to alphabetize then remove duplicates out of this array. Then I am trying to write each element in the array to its own line in a text file.

Meaning only one element of the sorted and unique array will be on a line.

But all I am getting is a blank text file.

How can I write the contents of this array, `$sorted_lines` to a text file so that each element is on a new line?

Here is my code:

```
<?php
$lines = file('american.txt');
$lines = array_walk($lines, 'trim'); 
$sorted_lines = sort(array_unique($lines));
$out = fopen("new.txt", "w");
foreach($sorted_lines as $line){
    $line .= "\n";
    fwrite($out, $line);
}
?>
```

Comment: Try throwing some debug information in there. First, are there lines to begin with? Do a print_r on $lines and see if there is anything there. Second, surround the fopen in an IF. `if (fopen("new.txt", "w")) { //do work }` Third, close the handle. `fclose($out);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[array_walk()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) and [sort()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php) are both pass by reference , with the return value being a boolean true/false for success/failure

```
array_walk($lines, 'trim');
$sorted_lines = array_unique($lines);
sort($sorted_lines);
```

Answer (score 1):

In the functions `array_walk()` and `sort()`, the first parameter is passed by reference, not value. This means that the function directly modifies the first parameter, instead of returning the result. `array_walk()` returns a boolean indicating whether or not the function works, not the array; therefore, the function is setting `$lines=1`. `sort()` does the same thing.

In the PHP documentation, you can tell that a parameter is passed by reference by it being preceeded by an ampersand; for example, the `sort` declaration looks like this:

```
bool sort ( array &$array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_REGULAR ] )
```

Note now the first parameter is `&$array`, not `$array`. This is the same way you declare references in custom functions.